# Raspbian - SQLite, Nextcloud - file locked

Tags: raspbian, sqlite, nextcloud

I have a Rpi 3b+ on raspbian setup on sqlite and nextcloud.

I run the below command:

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ files:scan --all
```

get the below output:

```
Starting scan for user 1 out of 1 (pi)
Exception during scan: "files/188f1ba3ad89878fcf6e89bb6dfa8f6e" is locked
#0 /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/Storage/Common.php(709): OC\Lock\DBLockingProvider->acquireLock('files/188f1ba3a...', 2)
#1 /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/Storage/Wrapper/Wrapper.php(592): OC\Files\Storage\Common->acquireLock('scanner::', 2, Object(OC\Lock\DBLockingProvider))
#2 /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/Cache/Scanner.php(331): OC\Files\Storage\Wrapper\Wrapper->acquireLock('scanner::', 2, Object(OC\Lock\DBLockingProvider))
#3 /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/Utils/Scanner.php(244): OC\Files\Cache\Scanner->scan('', true, 3)
#4 /var/www/html/nextcloud/apps/files/lib/Command/Scan.php(161): OC\Files\Utils\Scanner->scan('/pi')
#5 /var/www/html/nextcloud/apps/files/lib/Command/Scan.php(234): OCA\Files\Command\Scan->scanFiles('pi', '/pi', false, Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), false)
#6 /var/www/html/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(264): OCA\Files\Command\Scan->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /var/www/html/nextcloud/core/Command/Base.php(161): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /var/www/html/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(874): OC\Core\Command\Base->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/html/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(228): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(OCA\Files\Command\Scan), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Console/Application.php(173): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/nextcloud/console.php(90): OC\Console\Application->run()
#13 /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ(11): require_once('/var/www/html/n...')
#14 {main}

+---------+-------+--------------+
| Folders | Files | Elapsed time |
+---------+-------+--------------+
| 0       | 0     | 00:00:00     |
+---------+-------+--------------+
```

I tried to do the below link:

https://help.nextcloud.com/t/file-is-locked-how-to-unlock/1883

wasn't really of much help since I'm on sqlite. can somebody please help me & guide me here as to what's happening?

yes it started since an unexpected "freeze" of my pi and I had to pull the plug.

TIA

Additional Info:

- The pi has Transmission running on background downloading "files" :P
- three jobs run upon startup - one to startup ngrok
- one loop with the below command running every 5 mins:
  `sudo chmod 777 /location/to/data/data -R`
- one loop with the below command running every 5 mins:
  `sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ files:scan --all -v`

the reason? I need to be able to "see" & "action" the files in nextcloud web interface that I paste from the server and not using the web interface. because the files will be download by torrent to be made available in the nextcloud web interface.

Torrent Client : Transmission

all users are added to all groups (if you think I missed something here, pls let me know)

the permissions are set so because I have OSMC also as an optional OS that I use to watch movies and all.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it somehow, I had created a user "test" with a password and gave it to my friends to test the new server. they added & deleted files. I am guessing it's because of that. now that I added the user back, I'm not having the error anymore. gotta investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had deleted one user. adding the user back has solved the error. now I'll have to figure out a "safe" way to delete the user.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.